# KoaJS how to get files from multipart form data?

Tags: node.js, forms, koa

When I post a multipart form,

```
<form name="acount_manage"  action="/update" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

It throws:

```
Error: Unsupported content-type: multipart/form-data
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\...\node_modules\co-body\lib\any.js:51:15)
```

any.js:

```js
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var json = require('./json');
var form = require('./form');
var text = require('./text');

var JSON_CONTENT_TYPES = [
  'application/json',
  'application/json-patch+json',
  'application/vnd.api+json',
  'application/csp-report',
  'application/ld+json'

];

/**
 * Return a a thunk which parses form and json requests
 * depending on the Content-Type.
 *
 * Pass a node request or an object with `.req`,
 * such as a koa Context.
 *
 * @param {Request} req
 * @param {Options} [opts]
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

module.exports = function(req, opts){
  req = req.req || req;

  // parse Content-Type
  var type = req.headers['content-type'] || '';
  type = type.split(';')[0];

  // json
  if (~JSON_CONTENT_TYPES.indexOf(type)) return json(req, opts);

  // form
  if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' == type) return form(req, opts);

  // text
  if ('text/plain' == type) return text(req, opts);

  // invalid
  return function(done){
    var message = type ? 'Unsupported content-type: ' + type : 'Missing content-type';
    var err = new Error(message);
    err.status = 415;
    done(err);
  };
};
```

then,I changed the code

```
if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' == type) return form(req, opts);
```

to

```
if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' == type || 'multipart/form-data'==type) return form(req, opts);
```

no error ,but I can't get the request'data :

```
debug(this.request.files.file);
```

Result is undefined.

I am using KoaJs.

Answer (score 2):

For **koa 2**, try [async-busboy](https://github.com/m4nuC/async-busboy) to parse request body as
[co-busboy](https://github.com/cojs/busboy) doesn't play well with promise based async.

Example from the docs:

```
import asyncBusboy from 'async-busboy';

// Koa 2 middleware
async function(ctx, next) {
  const {files, fields} = await asyncBusboy(ctx.req);

  // Make some validation on the fields before upload to S3
  if ( checkFiles(fields) ) {
    files.map(uploadFilesToS3)
  } else {
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

Comment: [async-busboy](https://github.com/m4nuC/async-busboy) has an [issue generating ReadStreams](https://github.com/m4nuC/async-busboy/issues/1), so it's not reliable for multiple files upload yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try [koa-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-body) library.

Example:

Put this middleware BEFORE the route middleware:

```
app.use(require('koa-body')({
    formidable:{
        uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads', // directory where files will be uploaded
        keepExtensions: true // keep file extension on upload
    },
    multipart: true,
    urlencoded: true,
}));
```

Then use in route middleware

```
async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.request.body.files.file  // file is the input name
}
```

This code is for KoaJs 2, but this library works with KoaJs 1 too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First of all the code you are posting is the source code from `co-body` so adding in `multipart/form-data` isn't magically going to force this package to handle multi part data if it wasn't built to do so.

Rather than using [co-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-body) you can use [co-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-busboy) which was built to handle `multipart/form-data`.